# Windows 7 task bar program jump list

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, toolbar, jumplist

I am looking for a way to make a jump list for the windows task bar for application shortcuts. Kinda like the quick launch toolbar but with the jump list look. I tried to make my own 'toolbar' but that does what the quick launch bar did before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this program: [Jump List Launcher](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/jumplist-launcher-how-to-create-custom-jump-list-in-windows-7/) . It lets you create your own list of shortcuts to programs or whatnot, and is a true jumplist in both appearance and functionality.

Comment: Thanks gave you the accepted answer since yours uses the actual jump list system.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't gotten around to trying it yet, but a while ago I found a program that I think does what you want: [7stacks](http://www.alastria.com/index.php?p=software-7s). (It doesn't look like a jump list though; it is glass instead.)

Comment: Your answer was what I was looking for but had to award it to eidylon since his uses the actual jump list tech. +1 tho

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to do this as an application than I would suggest getting a copy of Microsoft Visual C++ and writing a program that implements [ICustomDestinationList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378402(VS.85).aspx).

> **ICustomDestinationList Interface**
>
> Exposes methods that allow an application to provide a custom Jump List, including destinations and tasks, for display in the taskbar.

Comment: +1 But I really don't feel like learning C++ to do this lol